# Multiple installations of Client-Server app and OAuth redirect

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, azure-ad-graph-api

We develop .net core based web server app with web browser client. This app will be installed on our client's dedicated servers. Our app will include, among others, contacts and calendars and we want to allow users sharing data between our and cloud agendas (via Azure graph-api, Goods api) .
We registered our app in Azure (for now, we assume it will be very similiar for Google) and got some codes (client, secret etc.). Now, we are not sure, what's corrent auth/usage flow.

Client side - a new browser window will be displayd to the end user, asking for grand types and login, but then the server should ask for an access token, as it will interoperate then. As I understand - this is done by using "redirection_uri" going to the server address.
The main problem here is that when registering our app in cloud environment, limited redirection address list is defined and checked later with "redirect_uri" parameter. Our application will be installed on customers' servers and we don't want to force them to register their own applications in the cloud's administrations as they even will not have their own cloud subscriptions.

Edit 2020-11-18:
I'll try to describe again what is our task we want to find solution for:

- We develop web app with browser based clients
- We sell this app to other organizations and they will install it on their own servers and will have their own customers (final customers) using this app
- These organizations don't have to have O365 subscriptions
- We, as developers, want our internal app calendars and contacts (among others) to be connected to final customers' Azure/Google calendard and contacts.
- It means, that the synchronization itself will be between organization's instance of our app and their customer's Azure/Google calendars/contacts.

I'm sure this must be quite common problem but I have't found any reliable answer.

Comment: Your clients need to access their own Graph data or your Graph data? If your clients are O365 organization, they should have an AAD tenant, which will allow them to register their own application. If you are considering multi-tenant app, your clients won't need to register their own application, just grant access to your AAD app to access their data by using admin consent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent.

Comment: Allen, thank you for your answer and link, it might be useful in some scenarios. I updated information we want to achieve in my original question.

Comment: So your main concern is that there will be many customers (not end users). Each customer need to have a redirect url but there is a limitation of redirect urls in an Azure AD app?

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to handle the scenario. We registered our "Azure/cloud app" (in our Azure account) so that end customers can share their data. But our app, will be installed on many customer's servers. We cannot (and don't want) add redirects to theirs servers in our Azure account.